# Clickonce project post publish target

Tags: visual-studio, clickonce, publish, target

I have a WPF project in VS 2013. I need to rename setup.exe file in the target clickonce publish directory I specify as Publishing folder in my local file system. The installation folder is a web site URL. I created the powershell script and tried to use it with the Target Name="AfterPublish":

```
<Target Name="AfterPublish">
    <Exec Command="powershell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -file C:\script.ps1 -param $(PublishUrl)" />
</Target>
```

But in that case the script is called before files from app.publish folder will be copied to Publishing folder. Also I tried AfterTargets="MSDeployPublish" and AfterTargets="GatherAllFilesToPublish".
E.g.

```
<Target Name="CustomPostPublishActions" AfterTargets="MSDeployPublish" >
    <Exec Command="powershell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -file C:\script.ps1 -param $(PublishUrl)" />
</Target>
```

No errors in those cases and nothing is happened.
I use VS menu Build->Publish command to publish project.